# MYSQL subquery error "Operand should atleast contain one column"

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have an error with my SQL query;

```
mysql_query("
SELECT * from houses 
WHERE pcode=(
   SELECT outcode,(SQRT((pow((`x` -$x),2)) + (pow((`y` -$y),2)))) AS `distance` 
   FROM hwz_postcodes 
   WHERE `x` BETWEEN $xnegexp AND $xplusexp 
   AND `y` BETWEEN $ynegexp AND $yplusexp 
   ORDER BY `distance`
)");
```

Basically there is 2 tables one table has a list of houses with a corrosponding post code and the other table is a list of post codes. My query basically compares a post code to nearby postcodes, and shows nearby houses.

The subquery sucessfully finds the nearest postcodes and lists them in order of distance. Now i can put this into a while loop and then perform another query within that to look at the houses table, however it is not efficient.

Can anyone suggest a solution to the query, remembering that the initial subquery results need to be ordered by distance, where distance is stipulated by the square root formula shown.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You're asking pcode to equal outcode AND distance. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this...

```
 SELECT h.*
      , p.*
   FROM houses h
   JOIN hwz_postcodes p
     ON p.outcode = h.pcode
  WHERE p.x BETWEEN $xnegexp AND $xplusexp 
    AND p.y BETWEEN $ynegexp AND $yplusexp;
```